# How do I make a st_distance query in meters with two elixir Geo.Point locations?

Tags: postgis, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Let's say I have two latitude,longitude pairs. (for example, (10.786377, 106.700292), (10.787126, 106.725805)). I know these are 2.789 km apart.

I have a function

```
 def within(latitude, longitude, radius) do
    point2 = %Geo.Point{coordinates: {latitude, longitude}}
    query = from post in Post, where: st_distance(post.location, ^point2)  < ^radius,  select: post
    Repo.all(query)
  end
```

That `radius` unit is not meters.

With our two original points, this is the smallest distance I could get to include the other point:

```
Post.within(10.786377, 106.700292, 0.025523999)
```

That's about ~109.26 km per unit here. 1 degree at 106.700292 longitude is 111601 m x 0.025523999 = 2,848 m which is close to the known 2.789 km difference.

Is there a way to query based on meters, not degrees at a given latitude?

Comment: `%Geo.Point{coordinates: {latitude, longitude}}` should be flipped to `%Geo.Point{coordinates: {longitude, latitude}}`

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.

I was using `:geometry` as my type in migration. You need to use `:geography`

Answer (score 0):

To change this after-the-fact, you can change existing geometry columns to geography in a migration, e.g:

```
execute("ALTER TABLE cities ALTER COLUMN location TYPE geography(Point,4326);")
```